# FusionCharts won't work with NGBootstrap modals

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, fusioncharts

I am trying to get a click event on a FusionCharts graph to open an NgBootstrap modal window. The modal elements get inserted in the DOM but the `show` class doesn't get added.

This is what the result is when clicking on the chart and triggering the modal:

[image: Clicking inside the chart]

And this is what the normal result is, from clicking the button outside the chart:

[image: Clicking on the button]

The `app.component.ts` file:

```
<fusioncharts width="700"
              height="400"
              type="Column2d"
              (chartClick)="chartClick()"
              [dataSource]="dataSource">
</fusioncharts>

<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="plainModal()">Plain modal</button>
```

The `app.component.ts` file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { PlainModalComponent } from './plainmodal.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

    dataSource: Object;

    constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {


        // Preparing the chart data
        const chartData = [
            {
                label: "Venezuela",
                value: "290"
            },
            {
                label: "Saudi",
                value: "260"
            },
            {
                label: "Canada",
                value: "180"
            },
            {
                label: "Iran",
                value: "140"
            },
            {
                label: "Russia",
                value: "115"
            },
            {
                label: "UAE",
                value: "100"
            },
            {
                label: "US",
                value: "30"
            },
            {
                label: "China",
                value: "30"
            }
        ];
        // Chart Configuration
        const dataSource = {
            chart: {
                caption: "Countries With Most Oil Reserves [2017-18]", //Set the chart caption
                subCaption: "In MMbbl = One Million barrels", //Set the chart subcaption
                xAxisName: "Country", //Set the x-axis name
                yAxisName: "Reserves (MMbbl)", //Set the y-axis name
                numberSuffix: "K",
                theme: "fusion" //Set the theme for your chart
            },
            // Chart Data - from step 2
            data: chartData
        };
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    plainModal() {
        this.modalService.open(PlainModalComponent);
    }

    chartClick() {
        this.modalService.open(PlainModalComponent);
    }

}
```

The `plainmodal.component.ts` file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
    selector: 'ngbd-modal-content',
    template: `
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title">Hi there!</h4>
      <button type="button" class="btn-close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Hello!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="activeModal.close('Close click')">Close</button>
    </div>
  `
})
export class PlainModalComponent {
    constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) { }
}
```

My `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "modaltest",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/common": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/core": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/forms": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/localize": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/router": "^13.3.11",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^12.1.2",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.10.2",
    "angular-fusioncharts": "^4.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "fusioncharts": "^3.19.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.2.5",
    "@angular/cli": "^13.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^13.3.11",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.5.2"
  }
}
```

My `app.modul.ts` file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { FusionChartsModule } from "angular-fusioncharts";

// Import FusionCharts library and chart modules
import * as FusionCharts from "fusioncharts";
import * as charts from "fusioncharts/fusioncharts.charts";
import * as FusionTheme from "fusioncharts/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fusion";
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { PlainModalComponent } from './plainmodal.component';

// Pass the fusioncharts library and chart modules
FusionChartsModule.fcRoot(FusionCharts, charts, FusionTheme);

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent, PlainModalComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule, FusionChartsModule, NgbModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

---

**edit**

If I do this:

```
this.modalService.open(PlainModalComponent, {
        windowClass: 'show',
        backdropClass: 'show'
    });
```

Then the show class gets added to the window, but not the backdropclass. So, some progress, but still not ideal.

Comment: share a stackblitz

Comment: @NarenMurali I have tried for hours to get StackBlitz to work and it is so difficult I gave up. Here's where I got to: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7ndcat

Comment: @Sean what part of  FusionCharts graph click should open fusion chart?

Comment: @Sean how about trying like this `(chartClick)="chartClick.bind(this)()"`

Comment: @NarenMurali same result - something still seems to be preventing the `show` classes being added.

Comment: @Sean Sorry even I am unable to get a working stackblitz or codesandbox for this issue! to fix it

Comment: Thanks, @NarenMurali. I appreciate your efforts. I'm trying but these fiddle sites are so temperamental. Currently getting an error trying to run fusioncharts on codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-moon-ebi7s6

Comment: Seems to be something to do with `ng-bootstrap`'s `onStable` event emitter. The 'zone' that the click event is running in for the chart click is stable, so it doesn't emit an onStable event, which is when the `show` class gets added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is being caused by FusionCharts running outside of the Angular 'zone'.

[image]

See:
https://github.com/fusioncharts/angular-fusioncharts/blob/develop/src/angular-fusioncharts/src/fusioncharts.component.ts#L476

To fix it, try:

```
constructor(private modalService: NgbModal, private zone: NgZone) {}

chartClick() {
    this.zone.run(() => {
        this.modalService.open(PlainModalComponent);
    });        
}
```